# How many questions needed to lower probability of passing multiple choice while guessing

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I try to solve the following exercise:

> A multiple choice exam has n questions. Each question has $3$ answers of
>   which only one can be valid. The student requires $60\%$ correct answer
>   to pass the exam. How many questions are needed so that the student
>   has a probability of  $(\le 0.1\%)$ to pass the exam while guessing the
>   answers.

I am stuck with this exercise. With $X$ for passing the exam
$$X \sim B(p=\frac{1}{3},n=?)$$

$P(X \geq ?) \leq 0.001$ but am not sure how to go with that.

Comment: $P(X\ge 0.6n)$ but this is still far from providing a way to solve for $n$.

Comment: In excel, I found $n=47$. I used the formula: 1-Binom.dist(0,6*n; n; 1/3; true) and $n$ varies . And then tested with the IF function: IF(A1<0.0001; true;false) if the value that I found is less than 0.1.

Comment: The result is supposed to be 12 correct answers. I will check barak manos's hint.

Comment: I compared wtih 0.0001 instead of 0.001 sorry. So, now I get 30 instead of 47. So, 30 questions (in total) are needed.

Answer (score 0):

HINT - You need to solve the following inequality:

$$\sum\limits_{k=\lceil0.6n\rceil}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\cdot\left(\frac13\right)^{k}\cdot\left(1-\frac13\right)^{n-k}<0.001$$